# Почему модальное окно Bootstrap перекрывается другим элементом?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Все индексы и позиции расставлены, даже игрался с прозрачностью, Яндекс Карты всё равно перекрывают!!!

Модальное в сайдбаре, Яндекс карты в контенте.
[Вот линк на проблему](http://crm4.arion72.ru/catalog/map)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Модальное окно должно располагаться в корне body.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

> #### Расположение разметки модального окна
>
> Старайтесь расположить разметку для модального окна как можно выше в DOM-дереве, чтобы избежать воздействия других компонентов на внешний вид и/или функционал модального окна.